# Я не могу сделать смайлики анимации css svg похожими на анимацию Pinterest

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Я не могу создать CSS-анимацию со своим SVG-спрайтом, похожим на Pinterest. В спрайте  90 кадров, но я не могу заставить его работать.

Pinterest анимация Emojis

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[View Pinterest Sprite 90 frames in Svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILB9G.png)

Мой код:

```css
.emoji{
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background-image : url(https://s.pinimg.com/webapp/style/images/wow-0a7ea725.svg);
  animation: moveX 1s steps(90) infinite;
}

@keyframes moveX{
  from{background-position-x:0px;}
  to{background-position-x:-500px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
```

Мой [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u81xkcon/)

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [I Can't make css svg animation emoji similar to Pinterest reactions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65516030/7394871) от участника  [@David Puma Rios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14893320/david-puma-rios).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/65516030/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Примерно так:

```css
.emoji {
  width: 110px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-image: url(https://s.pinimg.com/webapp/style/images/wow-0a7ea725.svg);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  animation: moveX 1s steps(90) infinite;
}

.emoji::before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%; /* keep the square ratio */
}

@keyframes moveX {
  to {
    background-position: right; /* you only need to move to right */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="emoji"></div>
<div class="emoji" style="width:50px"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65518196/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>